# Is it better to user const <variable name> = require(<package name>); or import '<Component Name>' from '<package name>'; If yes, could you show me?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, koa, koa-router, koa-bodyparser

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

BACKEND/package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "lkh-krishen",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@koa/router": "^10.1.1",
    "koa": "^2.13.4",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.7.0"
  }
}
```

BACKEND/index.js

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');


const productRoutes = require('./routes/products.routes');
const promotionRoutes = require('./routes/promotions.routes');

const app = new Koa();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(productRoutes.routes()).use(productRoutes.allowedMethods());
app.use(promotionRoutes.routes()).use(promotionRoutes.allowedMethods());

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Application is running on port 3000");
});
```

BACKEND/dal/index.js

```
const {MongoClient} = require("mongodb");

const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

client.connect(err => {
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB");
});

module.exports = client;
```

BACKEND/dal/products.dao.js

```
const products = require('./index').db('store').collection('products');

const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

const save = async ({name, description, qty, price}) => {
    const result = await products.insertOne({name, description, qty, price});
    //console.log(result.ops);
    return await getById(result.insertedId)
    //return result;
}

const getAll = async () => {
    const cursor = await products.find();
    return cursor.toArray();
}

const getById = async (id) => {
    return await products.findOne({_id:ObjectId(id)});
}

const update = async (id, {name, description, qty, price}) => {
    const result = await products.replaceOne({_id:ObjectId(id)}, {name, description, qty, price});
    return result.ops[0];
}

const removeById = async id => {
    await products.deleteOne({_id:ObjectId(id)});
}

module.exports = {save, getAll, getById, update, removeById};
```

BACKEND/api/products.api.js

```
const {getAll, save, update, getById, removeById} = require('../dal/products.dao');

const createProduct = async ({name, description, qty, price}) => {
    const product = {
        name,
        description,
        qty,
        price
    }
    return await save(product);
}

const getProducts = async () => {
    return await getAll();
}

const getProduct = async id => {
    return await getById(id);
}

const deleteProduct = async id => {
    return await removeById(id);
}

const updateProduct = async (id, {name, description, qty, price}) => {
    return await update(id, {name, description, qty, price});
}

module.exports = {createProduct, getProducts, getProduct, deleteProduct, updateProduct};
```

BACKEND/routes/products.routes.js

```
const Router = require('@koa/router');

const {createProduct, deleteProduct, updateProduct, getProduct, getProducts} = require('../api/products.api');

const router = new Router ({
    prefix: '/products'
});

router.get('/', async ctx => {
    ctx.body = await getProducts();
});

router.post('/', async ctx => {
    let product = ctx.request.body;
    product = await createProduct(product);
    ctx.response.status = 200;
    ctx.body = product;
});

router.get('/:id', async ctx => {
    const id = ctx.params.id;
    ctx.body = await getProduct(id);
});

router.delete('/:id', async ctx => {
    const id = router.params.id;
    ctx.body = await deleteProduct(id);
});

router.put('/:id', async ctx => {
    const id = ctx.params.id;
    
    let product = ctx.request.body;
    product = await updateProduct(product);
    
    ctx.response.status = 200;

    ctx.body = product;
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The choice of [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) or [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) is very much a personal choice, and therefore, not a good question for Stack Overflow. There are [many online resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=esm+vs+commonjs) which compare ESM and CommonJS; I suggest you look through those to help yourself make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

backend/api/customer.api.js

```
import { Customer } from '../models/Customer.js';
import {randomBytes} from 'crypto'

const customerList = new Map();
//
export const saveCustomer = ({ name }) => {
    const newCustomer = new Customer(
        randomBytes(16).toString('hex'),
        name,
        [],
        []
    );

    customerList.set(newCustomer.id, newCustomer);

    return newCustomer;
}

export const addToCart = (customerId, { item }) => {
    const customer = getCustomer(customerId);
    customer.cart.push(item);
    console.log(customer);
    customerList.set(customerId, customer);
}

export const viewCart = (customerId) => {
    const customer = getCustomer(customerId);
    return [...customer.cart];
}

export const addToWishList = (customerId, { item }) => {
    const customer = getCustomer(customerId);
    customer.wishList.push(item);
    console.log(customer);
    customerList.set(customerId, customer);
}

export const viewwishList = (customerId) => {
    const customer = getCustomer(customerId);
    return [...customer.wishList];
}

export const listAllCustomers = () => {
    return [...customerList.values()];
}

const getCustomer = (id) => {
    return customerList.get(id);
}
```

backend/models/Customer.js

```
export class Customer {
    constructor(id, name, cart, wishList) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cart = cart;
        this.wishList = wishList;
    }
}
```

backend/router/customer.router.js

```
import Router from '@koa/router'
import { saveCustomer, listAllCustomers, addToCart, addToWishList, viewCart, viewwishList } from '../api/customer.api.js'

const customerRouter = new Router({
    prefix: '/customers'
});

customerRouter.post('/save', (ctx) => {
    const data = ctx.request.body;
    console.log(`Data: ${data}`)
    ctx.body=saveCustomer(data);
    ctx.set('Content-Type','application/json')
    ctx.status = 201;
});

customerRouter.put('/:customerId/addToCart', (ctx) => {
    const id = ctx.params.customerId;
    ctx.body = addToCart(id, ctx.request.body);
    ctx.set('Content-Type','application/json')
    ctx.status = 200;
});

customerRouter.put('/:customerId/addToWishList', (ctx) => {
    const id = ctx.params.customerId;
    ctx.body = addToWishList(id, ctx.request.body);
    ctx.set('Content-Type','application/json')
    ctx.status = 200;
});

customerRouter.get('/customerId/viewCart', (ctx)=>{
    const id = ctx.params.customerId;
    ctx.body = viewCart(id);
    ctx.set('Content-Type','application/json')
    ctx.status = 200;
});

customerRouter.get('/customerId/viewWishList', (ctx)=>{
    const id = ctx.params.customerId;
    ctx.body = viewwishList(id, ctx.request.body);
    ctx.set('Content-Type','application/json')
    ctx.status = 200;
});

customerRouter.get('/', (ctx)=>{
    ctx.body = listAllCustomers();
    ctx.set('Content-Type','application/json')
    ctx.status = 200;
});

export default customerRouter;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const StudentGroupModel = mongoose.Schema({

    students: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: false,
        ref:'User'
    }],

    topic: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },

    supervisor: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: false,
        ref:'User'
    },

    co_supervisor: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: false,
        ref: 'User'
    },

    attachments:[{
        type: String,
        required: false,
    }],

    panel: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        retuired: false,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
        
});

const StudentGroup = mongoose.model('StudentGroup', StudentGroupModel);
module.exports = StudentGroup;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.